# AWS S3 correct credentials integration for Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html#step-3-get-aws-credentials), in order to use the s3 service for the AWS SDK on Android, it's mandatory to provide the Account Credentials through Cognito. However, in my organization, we do not use that service.

Is this the only proper way to connect to the service and integrate to my android app? I only have the information of the Token such as follows:

```
('AWS_S3_REGION', 'sa-east-1'); 
('AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY', 'MYHAPPYKEY'); 
('AWS_S3_SECRET', 'xyz/MYHAPPYSECRET'); 
('AWS_S3_BUCKET', 'my.happy.bucket'); 
('AWS_S3_BUCKET_SUFFIX', '.dev');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems that I could use the BasicAWSCredentials object and create my Client and use it as I would have created with Cognito

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
s3Client.setRegion(MY_REGION);
```

Comment: how do you get AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY, if you are storing this on device, you are making a huge security lapse.

Comment: I never mentioned I'm exposing the AWS sensitive information in the device. I'm aware of security affairs. There are many techniques for retrieveing the API keys. One reference I tried was as this tutorial states https://www.techjini.com/blog/securing-api-key-and-secret-key-in-android/

Another alternative is to consuming from a secure endpoint that sensitive information.

Comment: yup, I am consuming it from endpoint. thanks. I will have better control on what I am passing in case of any change in keys.